# Arranging Class Structure at Compile Time according to Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, enable-if

Is is possible in C++ to include/exclude a member variable based on template parameters?

Here is an example:

```
template< class T >
class RealNumber
{
    T real;
};

template< class T >
class ComplexNumber
{
    T real;
    T imag;
};
```

As they have many common properties, having only one class to represent a number ( with extra template parameter ) may prevent some code duplications.

What I wanted to do is something like

```
template< class T , class U >
Number
{
    T real;

    // If U is not void
    U imag;
}
```

So if second parameter is void, there would be no member named imag, yielding:

```
sizeof( Number< T , void > ) == sizeof( T )
```

I tried enable_if but couldn't get any result.

If this is not possible, are there any hacks that can make this possible?

Comment: You could just make it `Number<T>` and branch on whether `T` is fundamental or `std::pair<U,W>`.

Comment: Boost has a compressed pair type that might interest you.  I believe it is called `compressed_pair`.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose I tried compressed_pair and it works well. Although it can only make one variable included/excluded, it can be hacked to make it for multiple variables. I'll look into it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef NullType struct {} NullType;
template< class T , class U = NullType>
class Number
{
  T real;
  U image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the inheritance trick is viable for you:

```
template<class T, class = void >
class RealNumber
{
  protected: T real;
};

template<class T, class U>
class ComplexNumber : public RealNumber<T>
{
  U imag;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I wanted.

Comment: @MustafaSerdarŞanlı, What is the problem with this approach. You cannot certainly do what you are asking in the question. Because, think about a simple scenario: if `U` is `void` then what will happen to the methods containing it ?? Many such flaws can be found. In the solution above, you can systematically approach your problem.

Comment: if I cannot certainly do what I am asking in the question then please write another answer and explain the reason and I will accept that answer. I want to have a class named Number which can have one or two member variables based on template parameters. But in your example I have to use two different class names for my variables which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is incomplete and only shows how to use `enable_if` for specialization of class template.

```
template<class T,class U,class Enable = void>
class Number
{
  T real;
  T imag;
};
template<class T,class U>
class Number<T,U,typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<U>::value>::type>
{
  T real;
};
```

The detail implementation depends on the exact nature of the problem.
Such as,

- If RealNumber to ComplexNumber conversion is allowed (i.e `is_a` relationship) , you might consider inheriting from one implementation to another.
- To reuse large number of properties one can implement the common part in a private base class.
- Depending on exact problem, one can check if them template parameter `U` is really needed. Also what should be the preferred syntax for real number `Number<int,void>` or just `Number<int>`. etc.

Comment: I tested your code in g++, it works but there is a problem, `Number< int , int >` and `Number< int , int , void >` both have 8 bytes size  although second one does not have imag variable. What I want to achieve is `sizeof( Number< int , int , void > ) == 4`

Comment: @Mustafa: Perhaps you would be better served stating your problem, instead of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say where you're driving at, but here's a rough skeleton:

```
template <typename T> class Number
{
  template <typename S> class Adder
  {
    typedef S type;
    static type add(type a, type b) { return a + b; }
  };
  template <typename U, typename W> class Adder<std::pair<U,W>>
  {
    typedef typename std::pair<U,W> type;
    static type add(type a, type b) { return type(a.first + b.first, a.second + b.second); }
  };

  T val;

public:
  T operator+(const T rhs) { return Adder<T>::add(val, rhs); }
};
```

Note that most standard library numerical functions are already overloaded for the `std::complex` types, so you may want to think a bit about whether you really need to write this yourself.

Usage: `Number<int>`, `Number<double>`, `Number<std::pair<double, double>>`.

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is not to make a Number class. I wrote this example to easily show what I am trying to achieve. Your example doesn't work for me because I want to be able to include/exclude more than one variable.